# AWS CLI get download S3 URL for private bucket from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I could upload a file to a **private** S3 bucket successfully using following command:

`aws s3 cp "myfile.txt" "s3://myfolder/myfile.txt" --region=us-east-1 --output=json`

I would like to issue a AWS CLI command to return me a temporary URL download for myfile.txt and does anyone know how to?

I googled and look like I have to do some signing to get temporary URL such as: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

Comment: I found something related to URL signing: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_QSAuth.html but not sure yet how to use it.

Comment: https://github.com/dyashkir/amazon-s3-url-signer something related to this.

Comment: Not helpful yet, just for future reference: According to the aws-cli feature request [Support generation of signed URL's for S3 access](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/462), this functionality will be added sooner or later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I googled around and decided write this script to help me to generate singed-url for S3.

https://github.com/gdbtek/aws-tools

Comment: For all those coming here today, since this post the aws cli was updated and now you can actually simply use:
$ aws s3 presign s3://bucket/key --expires-in (seconds)

Answer (score 37):

aws cli now supports `presign` command. You can run

```
$ aws s3 presign s3://test-bucket/test-file.txt
https://test-bucket/test-file.txt?Expires=1499152189&Signature=some-sha
```

This will generate an url which you can share it with anyone to download that file in 3600 seconds.

You can change time period with `--expires-in`

```
$ aws s3 presign s3://test-bucket/test-file.txt --expires-in 600
```

The generated url will expire in 10 minutes.

You can read more about [presign in aws cli docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html).

Comment: How do I then use the presigned url to download the file?

Comment: Paste the url in browser.

Comment: If you paste the URL to browser and get this error: `The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.` You should add a region parameter to awscli: `aws s3 presign s3://test-bucket/test-file.txt --expires-in 600 --region eu-central-1`

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following URL format:

```
https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object or key name>
```

or old style:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/<object or key name>
```

To have it accessible you need to allow public access to your object or attach an appropriate bucket policy.

For example the following bucket policy shows public access to bucket `zzzyyy` object 'yyyeee'

```
$ aws s3 get-object-acl --bucket zzzyyy --key yyyeee
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "owner",
        "ID": "Some hash of owner"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "owner",
                "ID": "Some hash of owner"
            },
            "Permission": "READ"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "owner",
                "ID": "Some hash of owner"
            },
            "Permission": "WRITE"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "owner",
                "ID": "Some hash of owner"
            },
        "Permission": "READ_ACP"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "owner",
                "ID": "Some hash of owner"
            },
            "Permission": "WRITE_ACP"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"
            },
            "Permission": "READ"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"
            },
            "Permission": "READ_ACP"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see examples of bucket policies here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html

You can also use the S3 Console as seen here:

[image: S3 Console]

Comment: I forgot to mention that my bucket is private so I guess signing url is required?

Comment: I got following errors saying that get-boject-acl it not an options: # aws s3 get-object-acl --bucket mybucket --key blahblah
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

Comment: @NamNguyen No need to sign if your object within the bucket is public.

Comment: @NamNguyen do you have the latest version of the aws command line? Type `aws s3 help` to see the list of available options.

Comment: Look like I have latest version: # aws --version
aws-cli/1.2.6 Python/2.7.3 Linux/3.8.0-29-generic

Comment: my object in S3 bucket is not public so your solution would not work, right?

Comment: @NamNguyen public permissions will not work but you can setup your bucket policy according depending on what permissions you want.  You can also take advantage of IAM (http://aws.amazon.com/iam/)

Comment: @Rico: the latest version of aws-cli (1.3.7) does not support "get-object-acl".

Answer (score 3):

The command is wrong; instead of:

```
$ aws s3 get-object-acl --bucket zzzyyy --key yyyeee
```

It should be:

```
$ aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket zzzyyy --key yyyeee
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can take a look at https://github.com/minio/mc and give us feedback. We always wanted to have a CLI dropbox interface, of course not as GUI but scriptable and to be automated. So we ended up implementing a convenient command for `mc` to address two use cases.

- For sharing URLs to download files (Presigned Get)
- For sharing `curl` form to upload files (Presigned POST Policy)

Following examples address both use cases.

```
$ mc share
NAME:
  mc share - Download and upload documents.

USAGE:
  mc share command [arguments...]

COMMANDS:
  download  Generate URL to download documents.
  upload    Generate ‘curl’ command to upload files.
  list      List the shared URLs
```

These commands can be used in regular sense or also from with in a script. For  scripting purposes `mc` provides `--json` output for all the commands.

### Example for `mc share download`

```
$ mc share download https://s3.amazonaws.com/ferenginar/sur_2013-08-05T05_48_49-07_00.mp3
https://s3.amazonaws.com/ferenginar/sur_2013-08-05T05_48_49-07_00.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJVA5BMMU2RHO6IOQ%2F20151109%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20151109T060251Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=3c69928bee38b7b465547f9fa97146ff606480bbead8042c0351840c578a2ceb

$ mc --json share download https://s3.amazonaws.com/ferenginar/sur_2013-08-05T05_48_49-07_00.mp3 | jq .

{
  "expiry": {
    "days": 7
  },
  "downloadUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ferenginar/sur_2013-08-05T05_48_49-07_00.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJVA5BMMU2RHO6IOQ%2F20151109%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20151109T060618Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=48f7a521396ac8e36443cc86ce16c2619f9fa81371aad9a309375c933ea48d99",
  "keyName": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ferenginar/sur_2013-08-05T05_48_49-07_00.mp3"
}
```

### Example for `mc share upload`

```
$ mc share upload --expire=2h --content-type=image/png https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup/2007-Mar-2/... 
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup -F x-amz-credential=AKIAJVA5BMMU2RHO6IOQ/20151109/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request -F x-amz-date=20151109T061202Z -F x-amz-signature=61c234dd17fc9e5888417ac4546b37d61755e551674a9617f33f5232ec53c8b6 -F Content-Type=image/png -F bucket=backup -F policy=eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMS0wOVQwODoxMjowMi40MDZaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W1siZXEiLCIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwiaW1hZ2UvcG5nIl0sWyJlcSIsIiRidWNrZXQiLCJiYWNrdXAiXSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJGtleSIsIjIwMDctTWFyLTIvIl0sWyJlcSIsIiR4LWFtei1kYXRlIiwiMjAxNTExMDlUMDYxMjAyWiJdLFsiZXEiLCIkeC1hbXotYWxnb3JpdGhtIiwiQVdTNC1ITUFDLVNIQTI1NiJdLFsiZXEiLCIkeC1hbXotY3JlZGVudGlhbCIsIkFLSUFKVkE1Qk1NVTJSSE82SU9RLzIwMTUxMTA5L3VzLWVhc3QtMS9zMy9hd3M0X3JlcXVlc3QiXV19 -F x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 -F key=2007-Mar-2/<FILE> -F file=@<FILE>

$ mc --json share upload --expire=2h --content-type=image/png https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup/2007-Mar-2/... | jq .
{
  "expiry": {
    "hours": 2
  },
  "uploadCommand": "curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup -F x-amz-signature=4b349a15e76ab403424ec6b1e289336f67c02c427ccc98522d6f654eee5b7de6 -F Content-Type=image/png -F bucket=backup -F policy=eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMS0wOVQwODoxMzoyMS4zODFaIiwiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6W1siZXEiLCIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwiaW1hZ2UvcG5nIl0sWyJlcSIsIiRidWNrZXQiLCJiYWNrdXAiXSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJGtleSIsIjIwMDctTWFyLTIvIl0sWyJlcSIsIiR4LWFtei1kYXRlIiwiMjAxNTExMDlUMDYxMzIxWiJdLFsiZXEiLCIkeC1hbXotYWxnb3JpdGhtIiwiQVdTNC1ITUFDLVNIQTI1NiJdLFsiZXEiLCIkeC1hbXotY3JlZGVudGlhbCIsIkFLSUFKVkE1Qk1NVTJSSE82SU9RLzIwMTUxMTA5L3VzLWVhc3QtMS9zMy9hd3M0X3JlcXVlc3QiXV19 -F x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 -F x-amz-credential=AKIAJVA5BMMU2RHO6IOQ/20151109/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request -F x-amz-date=20151109T061321Z -F key=2007-Mar-2/<FILE> -F file=@<FILE> ",
  "keyName": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/backup/2007-Mar-2/..."
}
```

Looking forward on some feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Know this is 8 months late, but I just found out you can use Eclipse with the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse (http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/) to generate pre-signed URLs with a right-click on the target file, even lets you set the expy date....It's pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any pre built cli command \sub command to get private bucket url, for pre-sign you can refer [presign](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html) .
In case if you want a public url in private bucket, that is object read is public not bucket.
For public aws url, you can use something - I have written this in powershell, you can put this `$profile`

```
Function getAwsUrl{
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="S3Path")]
    param(
    [parameter (ParameterSetName="S3Path",mandatory=$true)]$s3path,
    [parameter (ParameterSetName="BucketKey")]$bucket,
    [parameter (ParameterSetName="BucketKey",mandatory=$true)]$key 
    )
if($s3path)
{
$splits = $s3path.Split('//')
$bucket =$splits[2]
$key = $splits[3]
}
else 
{
#user input bucket and key
$bucket =$bucket
$key = $key
}

#using standard aws region "us-west-2"
Write-Output "https://$bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/$key"
}
```

**Example usage**:
Make sure you pass `--acl` as public-read

```
aws s3 cp C:\temp\dumy.txt s3://fpd-uploads/ --acl public-read
getAwsUrl -s3path s3://fpd-uploads/dumy.txt
```

> get-help getAwsUrl

```
NAME
    getAwsUrl

SYNTAX
    getAwsUrl -s3path <Object>  [<CommonParameters>]

    getAwsUrl -key <Object> [-bucket <Object>]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```