# Is there a way to generate a presigned url for an S3 object using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I've looked at the documentation for `aws s3` and `aws s3api` but I can't see anything relevant to generating a presigned url. The AWS web docs only show examples for doing this with Java, .Net, and VisualStudio.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Comment: You can do it with python/boto as well...

Comment: Does the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392796/aws-cli-get-download-s3-url-for-private-bucket-from-aws-cli help you? (https://github.com/gdbtek/aws-tools)

Comment: Not there yet, hence for future reference only: According to the aws-cli feature request [Support generation of signed URL's for S3 access](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/462), this functionality will be added sooner or later.

Comment: A list of the available commands: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/index.html , so no, there isn't.

Answer (score 9):

This is available native in the aws cli now:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Note that you need to have a recent AWS CLI for this to work: https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip

Comment: This generates a GET request. What if I want a POST/PUT request?

Comment: Should be possible. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: @Jeroen unfortunately no AWS CLI support for presigning PUT mentioned there, only Java/.NET/Ruby SDKs.

Comment: @Jeroen @alexander-klimetschek It is possible but it's a little bit hacky. First in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/customizations/s3/subcommands.py` change `get-object` to `put-object`. Then do the presign with aws cli. Finally use `Curl` like this: `echo toto | curl --data-binary @- <url> -X PUT -H 'Content-Type:'` The sdks don't do any other magic than just sending the bytes from the http library.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for...

Sign an S3 URL to provide limited public access with expiry

```
s3cmd signurl s3://BUCKET/OBJECT <expiry_epoch|+expiry_offset>
```

http://s3tools.org/usage

It is not AWS API directly. It is a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it with `aws s3`, try with the `presign` option. For example, if you want to get an object from a bucket, try this command:

```
aws s3 presign s3://bucket_name/file_name
```

Replace the bucket_name and file_name by the ones of the object you want to get.